# Can't access apache from Internet

Tags: apache, ubuntu-14.04, firewall

It must be a common question but I've not found any appropriate answer:

I have a website on apache server running in my office LAN. I can view pages from all computers (even smart-phones via Wifi).

All computers are connected to a router (with static IPs) which supports port forwarding.

I forwarded the routers port 8080 to the internal IP 192.168.1.5:80 which is the apache box (xubuntu 14.04).

The problem is that when I try to view the site from the internet, I always get `connection refused` response. I tried the http://www.canyouseeme.org but still the response is the same. This happens both when I try from my LAN->Internet->Router->Apache or directly from home Internet->Router->Apache.
I know (rather suspect) that the routed does its job because if I hit the external static IP:80 I get into its interface while when I hit IP:8080 I get the `connection refused` response. Canyouseeme agrees (it times out as it's waiting for a password).

Funny(?) thing is that I have not installed a firewall and the `apache2.conf` is the default.

Can somebody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it is all clear; my ISP didn't allow to set the routers firewall so every setting I made was void.

So to recap first make sure that your ISP is really forwarding your ports.

However I couldn't up my site (zoneminder app) so I write down the solution in case someone else finds it useful:

First of all I assume that Apache is running without problems with the default settings. In case that you want to make a site (in your system you'll see directory) available as the root site of your apache serer, you must create a "rule" for apache:

First copy the `000-default.conf` file that lies in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/` directory (in Ubuntu systems) by executing

```
sudo cp /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/mysite.conf
```

The `mysite.conf` file will be a setting for virtual host and you will need to add/change contents accordingly with:

```
DocumentRoot /my/site/directory
    <Directory />
         Options FollowSymLinks
         AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /my/site/directory/>
         Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
         AllowOverride None
         Order allow,deny
         Allow from all
    </Directory>
```

Don't forget to change (if needed) the port apache is listening to by editing the `/etc/apache2/ports.conf`.